# Keep browser default font-size for multiple headings when setting other font properties using the font shorthand property

Tags: css, fonts, shorthand

Is it possible to tweak the default browser font properties of `h1` through `h6` using the font shorthand property **without** changing the `font-size`, something like this:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { font:400 normal/1.2 rockwell,sans-serif; }
```

I guess the alternative is not using shorthand (like below) but if it's possible it would be nice to know.

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
   font-weight:400;
   line-height:1.2;
   font-family:rockwell,sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, according to this (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font.asp):

> The font shorthand property sets all the font properties in one
>   declaration.
>
> The properties that can be set, are (in order): "font-style
>   font-variant font-weight font-size/line-height font-family"
>
> **The font-size and font-family values are required.** If one of the other
>   values are missing, the default values will be inserted, if any.

Comment: You're correct, but I hate that your referencing [W3Schools](http://w3fools.com/) so here's the answer [from the horses mouth](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-shorthand).